# How to use pointers in for loops to count characters?

Tags: c++

I was looking through the forums and saw a question about counting the numbers of each letter in a string. I am teaching myself and have done some research and am now starting to do projects. Here I have printed the elements of the array. But I do so without pointers. I know I can use a pointer to an array and have it increment for each value, but I need some help doing so.

Here is my code without the pointer:

```
code main() {
    char alph [] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    int i, o;
    o = 0;
    for(i=0; i < 3; i++)
        { cout << alph[i] << ' '; };
};
```

Here is my bad code that doesn't work trying to get the pointer to work.

```
main() {
    char alph [] = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
    char *p;
    p = alph;

    for (; p<=3; p++);
        cout << *p;

    return 0;
};
```

I hope that it's not too obvious of an answer; I don't mean to waste anyone's time. Also this is my first post so if anyone wants to give me advice, thank you.

Comment: The second doesn't compile because you've not specified a return type for `main()`.  The first only compiles if you've got a `typedef` for `code` that maps to an `int` type.  Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and note that questions where the code does not compile (but is supposed to) is usually frowned upon.

Comment: oh ok thanks, i didnt know that it didn't compile for the first. It worked for me so i just assumed it was right. thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Very good try. There's just one tiny thing wrong, which is this:

```
p <= 3
```

Pointers are just some number which represents a memory address. When you do `p = alph`, you're not setting `p` to `0`, you're setting it to point to the same address as `alph`. When looping over an array with pointers, you have to compare the current pointer with a pointer that is one past the end of the array. To get a pointer to one element past the end of the array, you add the number of elements to the array:

```
alph + 3 // is a pointer to one past the end of the array
```

Then your loop becomes

```
for (; p < alph + 3; ++p)
```

You may think that getting a pointer to one past the end of the array is going out of bounds of the array. However, you're free to get a pointer to *anywhere* in memory, as long as you don't dereference it. Since the pointer `alph + 3` is never *dereferenced* - you only use it as a marker for the end of the array - and everything is fine.

Here are some rough correlations for the different versions:

```
/-----------------------------------\
| Pointer Version |   Index Version |
-------------------------------------
|  p              |              i  |
|  p = alph       |          i = 0  |
|  *p             |        alph[i]  |
|  alph + 3       |              3  |
|  p < alph + 3   |          i < 3  |
\-----------------------------------/
```

Also note that instead of doing `alph + 3`, you may want to use `sizeof`. `sizeof` gives you the number of bytes that an object occupies in memory. For arrays, it gives you the number of bytes the whole array takes up (but it doesn't work with pointers, so you can do it with `alph` but not with `p`, for example). The advantage of using `sizeof` to get the size of the array is that if you change the size later, you do not have to go and find all the places where you wrote `alph + 3` and change them. You can do that like this:

```
for (; p < alph + sizeof(alph); ++p)
```

Additional note: because the size of `char` is defined to be `1` byte, this works. If you change the array to an array of `int`, for example (or any other type that is bigger than 1 byte) it will not work any more. To remedy this, you divide the total size in bytes of the array with the size of a single element:

```
for (; p < alph + sizeof(alph) / sizeof(*alph); ++p)
```

This may be a little complicated to understand, but all you're doing is taking the total number of bytes of the array and dividing it by the size of a single element to find *the number of elements in the array*. Note that you are adding *the number of elements in the array*, **not** *the size in bytes of the array*. This is a consequence of how pointer arithmetic works (C++ automatically multiplies the number you add to a pointer by the size of the type that the pointer points to).

For example, if you have

```
int alph[3];
```

Then `sizeof(alph) == 12` because each `int` is 4 bytes big. `sizeof(*alph) == 4` because `*alph` is the first element of the array. Then `sizeof(alph) / sizeof(alph)` is equal to `12 / 4` which is `3`, which is the number of elements in the array. Then by doing

```
for (; p < alph + sizeof(alph) / sizeof(*alph); ++p)
```

that is equivalent to

```
for (; p < alph + 12 / 4; ++p)
```

which is the same as

```
for (; p < alph + 3; ++p)
```

Which is correct.

This has the good advantage that if you change the array size to `50` and change the type to `short` (or any other combination of type and array size), the code will still work correctly.

When you get more advanced (and hopefully understand arrays enough to stop using them...) then you will learn how to use `std::end` to do all this work for you:

```
for (; p < std::end(alph); ++p)
```

Or you can just use the range-based `for` loop introduced in C++11:

```
for (char c : alph)
```

Which is even easier. I recommend understanding pointers and pointer arithmetic well before reclining on the convenient tools of the Standard Library though.

Also good job SO, you properly syntax-highlighted my ASCII-Art-Chart.

Comment: @Mysticial "You are now a trusted user" Thanks :)

Comment: Haha thanks Seth, i keep thinking you are finished teaching but you keep surprising me :D im happy to see so many people being so helpful, i have learned more right now than reading couple hours in my book.

Comment: @user1177261 yes, SO is a cool place. Good luck with learning C++. And I really am done now :) (unless you have further questions).

Comment: I wouldn't use `end` without `begin`, though, nor with less-than comparison. The power of generic constructions is that they are... generic :-)

Answer (score 3):

The pointer loop should be:

```
for (char * p = alph; p != alph + 3; ++p)
{
    std::cout << *p << std::endl;
}
```

You can get a bit more fancy by hoisting the end of the array out of the loop, and by inferring the array size automatically:

```
for (char * p = alph, * end = alph + sizeof(alph)/sizeof(alph[0]); p != end; ++p)
```

In C++11, you can do even better:

```
for (char c : alph) { std::cout << c << std::endl; }
```

Comment: just a question i understand that there is a difference btw ++p and p++ but is it important in this case and if so why?

Comment: @user1177261: Use the one that you *mean*. In this case, you only mean to increment the pointer, so use `++p`. In some rare cases (like erasing iterators) you *need* to increment but return a value of the original, in which case you use `it++`. But those occasions are not all that frequent.

Comment: In this context, there's no real difference.  In more complex circumstances, with iterators and things, pre-increment is preferred to post-increment.  It becomes an efficiency issue.  (Unreformed C programmers like me tend to use the post-increment most of the time; it is not a good habit to have in C++.)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem (apart from compilation issues noted in my comment to the question) is that pointers are not as small as `3`.  You need:

```
for (p = alph; p < alph + sizeof(alph); p++)
```

for the loop.  Note that `sizeof()` generates a compile-time constant.  (In C99 or C2011, that is not always the case; in C++, it is always the case, AFAIK).  In this context, `sizeof()` is a fancy way of writing `3`, but if you add new characters to the array, it adjusts automatically, whereas if you write `3` and change things, you have to remember to change the `3` to the new value too.

---

#### Ruminations on the use of `sizeof()`

As [Kerrek SB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb) points out, `sizeof()` returns the size of an array in bytes.  By definition, `sizeof(char) == 1`, so in this context, it was safe to use `sizeof()` on the array.  There are also times when it is not safe - or you have to do some extra work.  If you had an array of some other type, you can use:

```
SomeType array[] = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13 };
```

then the number of elements in the array is `(sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]))`.  That is, the number of elements is the total size of the array, in bytes, divided by the size of one element (also in bytes).

The other big gotcha is that if you 'pass an array' as a function argument, you can't use `sizeof()` on it to get the correct size - you get the size of a pointer instead.  This is a good reason for not using C-style strings or C-style arrays: use `std::string` and `std::vector<SomeType>` instead, not least because you can find their actual size reliably with a member function call.

Comment: It's worth noting (especially for a beginner) that `sizeof` does **not** return the array size, but rather the total memory size. It only so happens that the size of one unit is 1.

Comment: cool, now i know about sizeof() :D, so this is an example of implementing dynamic memory

Comment: @user1177261 no, dynamic memory would be allocated with `new`. `sizeof(alph)` is just a way for the compiler to calculate the size of an array for you. It happens to be `3` in this case (because it holds 3 `char`s and each one is `1` byte), so `alph + sizeof(alph)` is just like `alph + 3`. The advantage of using `sizeof` is that when you change the size of your array, you don't have to go back and redo all the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I recommand you the following revised code.

```
char alph [] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 0};
char *p;
p = alph;

while(*p)
{
    std::cout << *p++;
}
```

Comment: @user1177261 it will work as long as your array ends with a `0` and has no `0`s before the last element.

Comment: ah i see... so it wouldn't work very well with an array of numbers that contains a zero somewhere other than at the end.

Comment: I think it's nonsense about a string that has a zero('0') in the middle of in C/C++.

Comment: @KyokookHwang - I've seen null-delimited strings stored in a char[] before.  I think the array was holding settings for the ODBC API in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

0 marks the end of a string in both c and c++.